# Excel Dependent Drop Drown List from Another Workbook

Tags: excel, list, dropdown, excel-365

I was wondering is it able to create a dependent drop down list in excel from another workbook.

I was able to create the drop down list from another workbook. What I wanted now is that to create a **dependent drop down list** based on the previous drop down list that I have already created.

I searched for many times already but yet still can't get one.

Comment: Post here how you make dropdown list from another workbook then may understand.

Comment: I was using the name range. I follow the link to create the drop down list. https://www.contextures.com/xldataval05.html